# Как перезагрузить операторы ввода-вывода внутри класса? C++

Tags: c++, ооп

Я делал самописный BigInteger и возникли вопросы по поводу перезагрузки операторов ввода-вывода.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void resize(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b) //функция для того, чтобы сделать 2 числа одинаковыми по размеру. 999 + 99 <=> 999 + 099
{
    int i = a.size() - 1;
    for (; a.at(i) == 0; i--);
    a.resize(i + 1);
    i = b.size() - 1;
    for (; b.at(i) == 0; i--);
    b.resize(i + 1);
    if (a.size() > b.size())
    {
        while (b.size() != a.size())
        {
            b.push_back(0);
        }
    }
    if (a.size() < b.size())
    {
        while (b.size() != a.size())
        {
            a.push_back(0);
        }
    }
}

class bigint
{
    vector<int> digits;

public:

    bigint()
    {
        digits.push_back(1);
    }

    bigint(const string& s)
    {
        if (s.empty())
            this->digits.push_back(1);
        else
        {
            for (auto i = s.rbegin(); i != s.rend(); i++)
            {
                this->digits.push_back(*i - '0');
            }
        }
    }

    bigint operator+(bigint& another)
    {
        resize(this->digits, another.digits);
        int size = this->digits.size();
        int remainder = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            this->digits[i] += another.digits[i] + remainder;
            remainder = this->digits[i] / 10;
            this->digits[i] %= 10;
        }
        if (remainder == 1)
            this->digits.push_back(1);
        return *this;
    }

    bigint operator*(const int& another)
    {
        
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out)
    {
        for (auto i = this->digits.rbegin(); i != this->digits.rend(); i++)
        {
            out << *i;
        }
        return out;
    };
};



int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    bigint a("999"), b("999");
    cout << a + b;
}
```

Как сделать перезагрузить оператор `<<` и `>>` в самом классе? Очевидно, что моя реализация - неверна, потому что брать в аргументы функции `ostream` - бессмысленно, ведь в аргумент функции поступает `bigint` (по идее?). Хорошо, но?... Как тогда работает указатель this? То есть, вот моя функция (она тоже не рабочая, но если можно сделать рабочей хотелось бы знать как):

```
   std::ostream&  operator<<(const bigint& a)
    {
        ostream out;
        for (auto i = a.digits.rbegin(); i != a.digits.rend(); i++)
        {
            out << *i;
        }
        return out;
    };
```

У меня есть переменная `a`. И указатель `this` что ли на нее указывает?.. Хорошо тогда надо делать без аргументов что ли? `ostream& operator<<()`. Я не совсем этот момент понимаю.

Все же, как реализовать перезагрузку оператора внутри класса?

Comment: Возможно [здесь](https://www.cyberforum.ru/visual-cpp/thread1542146.html) вы найдёте ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: @DSuhoi да, спасибо

Comment: по ссылке не верный код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
friend  std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream& out, const bigint& a)    {
   
    //...
    return out;
};
```

Левый операнд оператора является объектом другого класса и возвращается ссылка на него, значит функция принадлежать может только этому классу и его наследникам, а для других может быть только другом или быть свободным оператором.

Вообще то я бы не хранил вектор, а хранил бы string  и написал бы отдельные функции для операций с символами, являющимся цифрами.

Comment: А почему бы вы предпочли через string реализовывать?

Comment: проще читать строку в string, чем в вектор, проще записывать и присваивать, проще реализовать все, что вы реализовали